# Force a certain icon size for JPopupMenu items?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, jpopupmenu

In my program I have Actions that have different-sized icons, some intended for large buttons and some for small.  I would like to reuse the same instance of each of these Actions when adding functionality to a JPopupMenu.  Is there a way to force the large icons to be displayed at a smaller size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Action`s API provides two icon keys.  `SMALL_ICON` and `LARGE_ICON_KEY`

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html)

> The JMenuItem subclasses only use SMALL_ICON. All other buttons will
>   use LARGE_ICON_KEY; if the value is null they use SMALL_ICON.

This would suggest that you should use the `SMALL_ICON` key for your actions to allow `JMenuItems` to display the small icon.